# Is there an option to track(goals) ajax form with checkbox that works screen by screen?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an ajax form with some questions of choice but every question will be displayed on new screen (screen by screen) by button.

I want to track users behavior on my form page. I want to know after which question user has left the page (which questions they filled up)

Also I would like to know from which devices they have visited the form page and how long they were on this page

Is it possible to track all of this by GA or GTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is screen-by-screen as you said, it sounds like you need to track two things.

- An event for clicking the "Next" button
- A virtual pageview for each screen.

This way, you can look into your Exit Pages report to see what screen the left the page from.

As for device tracking information, that type of data is automatically captured by GA.

So, basically.  You'd have a virtual pageview for the first screen (assuming this form is a popup modal).  If it's not a popup modal, then you'd just have the normal pageview for that first screen.

For instance, if the user has to click a link/button for the form to start, then you'd, ideally, fire an event for clicking that link/button, fire a virtual pageview when the first screen loads, fire an event when the user clicks the next button, then rinse and repeat for the subsequent screens.

Also, it may be a good idea to track the last screen's "next" button (or "finish") button as a separate event.  Then, you can see in your events report who has filled out all of the screens and submitted.

Another thing worth pointing out: If you also want to show which question was the last one filled out, you can provide the name of the question (or an id, or some kind of brief and canonical identifier) in the virtual pageview as a custom dimension.